# ExpressionEngine 2.4.0 and PHP 5.6 support

Tags: ee2

My service provider is planning on upgrading from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.6.

I'm currently running EE 2.4.0.

First of all will it work and secondly can I expect and issues after the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to get errors/warnings for not using MySQLi or PDO.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php

There's not a ton of functional deprecation from 5.4 to 5.6, so I predict you'll be fine. However, I highly recommend upgrading your EE install; it is foolish not to. To answer your question directly:

It will probably be a functional site; but expect PHP warnings and deprecation notices.

Comment: No problem! If you can get EE upgraded, you'll be fly! Just remember to run a full file and database backup before you upgrade!